# What could be causing me to get the YSOD: "Section blocks cannot be nested. Only one level of section blocks are allowed."?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, razor, ysod

I can see, indeed, that the code above the section flagged as suspicious above is wrong, because the closing "}" is not yellow.

At the top of the page I have some using directives:

```
@using System.Configuration
@model CCRReporter.Models.TLISReportModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Transaction Line Item Sales Report Criteria";
    ViewBag.PageName = ViewBag.Title;
}
```

...followed by a script section:

```
@section ScriptContent
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript" defer> </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript" defer> </script>
    // etc.

<script type="text/javascript">
        var bSubmitting = false;
        var WantsFocus = null;
        var bFocusing = false;
        var report_parms = null;

        function SetTabOrder() {
            $.each([
                "#BeginDate",
                "#BeginTime",
                "#EndDate",
                "#EndTime",
                "#InputSite-input",
                "#cmdAddSite",
                "#InputDept-input",
                "#cmdAddDept",
                "#IncludeDepts",
                "#ExcludeDepts",
                "#UPCBeginsWith"],
            function (i, n) {
                $(n).prop("taborder", "y");
            });
        }

        // ready handler
        $(function() {
    // etc.
```

...this jQuery has been validated via jsfiddle/jshint.

Here is the YSOD:

```
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Section blocks ("@section Header { ... }") cannot be nested.  Only one level of section blocks are allowed.

Source Error:

Line 402:}
Line 403:
Line 404:@section MainHead
Line 405:{
Line 406:    <link href="@Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Source File: /CCRReporter/Views/CCRCriteria/TLISReport.cshtml    Line: 404
```

I've looked over all this code multiple times, and have no idea what the problem is. Has anybody run into this before, or know of a trick for finding just where the problem lies?

Comment: Easy fix would probably be just placing your javascript in an external file and including it like the other js files. Otherwise, you'd need to escape all `}` inside the javascript somehow. i'm not familiar enough with asp.net to suggest how to do that.

Comment: Okay, I did that, leaving only the script references and the ready handler inside the Script section, and the same problem still holds.

Comment: Right... but the ready handler still has a closing `}`, wouldn't that close the @section too early?

Comment: Only if it didn't need one, or there was a superfluous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still couldn't find any syntactical problem with the code, but on closer inspection, the logic of the code seemed quite bizabre (combination of bizarre and macabre):

It had a submit_button click handler that called $("form").submit();

If "submit_button" really is a submit button (input type="submit") - and it is!, why would that be necessary? Not only that, but the function called from the click handler had been declared this way:

```
$("#form0").submit(function() {
```

form0? What the Hec Ramsey?!? There is no "Form0" anywhere on the page...

Once I moved the code for submitting from the Form0 handler (which, I admit, I had previously changed from selecting the phantom 'form0' to 'form') to the submit_button handler, the much-awaited and yearningly longed for yellow background returned to the section's ending "}".

Voila!

Maybe the debugger is smarter than I thought: it goes on strike not only when the code doesn't compile, but also at times, apparently, when it (the code, or, by extension, the carbon-based biped who wrote it) a candidate for the loony bin.

Alas -- I know why the caged bird sings: he was trapped maintaining the code of birdbrains who had flown the coop!